# Evaluate GCD series in best optimal way

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, gcd-and-lcm

I want to evaluate this function : 
$F(x) = 1/GCD(1,x) + 2/GCD(2,x) + ... + x/GCD(x,x)$

Is there any short formula rather than taking GCD with all numbers to evaluate this function for given x ?

Comment: what kind of number is $x$ here?

Comment: [This problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931448/intuitive-formula-for-gcd-series) just appeared from a different user.  What competition is it from?

Comment: @lulu this question hardly feels like a competition problem though

Comment: @N.S.JOHN  Well, a decent automation of the sum certainly seems feasible.  And the other user instantly deleted their post when asked about it.  If there's a better explanation, perhaps this OP can provide it?